# Partitioning sample for cross validation within subsets of the sample (by school) (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cross-validation

I need to partition a data set 5 ways for 5 fold cross validation using matlab. However, the dataset pertains to students nested in schools, so instead of splitting the entire data set 5 ways, I want to split each school 5 ways. After building 5 training and 5 test data sets I want to be able to tell which observations in each data set belong to each school.

In the full data set I have a feature vector x (28x15363) and target vector y (1x15363). I also have an index vector (task_indexes) that identifies the first observation for each school.

I would like to build a set of 5 training set indexes and 5 corresponding test set indexes based on a 5 fold partition of each school, and I will need a set of task indexes, 5 tr_indexes which identify the first observation of each school in each training set, and tsk_indexes which do the same for the test set.

The training set indexes tr, test set indexes tst, training set task indexes tr_indexes and test set task indexes tst_indexes should fit into the following code.

```
gammas = [.1, .01, .001, .0001, .00001]

errgrid = zeros(5,1)

for g = 1:length(gammas)
    gammas = gammas(4)
    [testerrs,theW,theD] = ...
        run_code_example(gammas, x(:, tr), y(tr), x(:, tst), y(tst), tr_indexes, tst_indexes, Dini, 10, 'feat', 0, fname);
    errgrid(g) = testerrs

gammaselect = gammas(min(errgrid))
```

In this code, I use a partition provided by the authors with training set indexes tr and test indexes tst, and task indexes tr_indexes for the training set and tst_indexes for the test set.

Any advice on how to carry out this partition?

I tried to write this post to the standard of writing a good question. If anyone can provide feedback to improve the question it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The first advice given in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (*essential* reading) is **Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague**. Nobody's actually interested in the "backstory" and the rationale (they are arguably irrelevant to the issue); I kindly suggest you edit the question removing any details that are not *directly* relevant with what you want to achieve (*why* you want to achieve it is, again, not relevant...)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Going to edit and pare down the problem now.